# Merging/Joining with data.table not identical to merge function

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to understand if I should use `data.table` or base r to merge `data.tables`.  These two methods produce an identical number of rows and cols and the same variables classes, but the `identical` function returns false.  I am trying to understand what is different between these two methods.

```
library( data.table )

a <- data.frame( 
    id = 1:10000000,
    var1 = sample(letters , 10000000,  replace=T ),
    var2 = sample(letters , 10000000,  replace=T ),
    var3= sample(letters , 10000000,  replace=T )
)

b <- data.frame( 
    id = 1:10000000,
    var4 = sample(letters , 10000000,  replace=T ),
    var5 = sample(letters , 10000000,  replace=T ),
    var6= sample(letters , 10000000,  replace=T )
)


a <- data.table( a )
b <- data.table( b )

system.time( dts <- a[b, on = .(id )] )
system.time( base <- merge( a , b, by = c("id") ) )

# returns FALSE
    identical( dts , base )

# BUT the classes and dims are the same
    sapply( dts , class  )
    sapply( base , class  )

    dim( base )
    dim( dts )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base` version has an additional attribute called `sorted`. This attribute is created by the default behavior of `merge`, if you do:

```
base <- merge( a , b, by = c("id"),sort = FALSE)
```

they are identical.